# Create clone on another function with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clone

It shows a message 'Hi' when I click on 'ShoW',
But when I click on the next option 'ShoW', it does not show a message.

```js
$('.btn').on("click", function () {
    alert('Hi');
    $('.box .btn').remove();
    $('.btn').clone().appendTo('.box'); 
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">ShoW</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

What code should I add for JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the event handler you created is bound to objects that existed when it was created:

```
$('.btn').on("click", function () {
```

This will only work for `.btn` elements that were already available at the time this line of code ran - it is not evaluated by jQuery again.

Instead, use this format for binding the event, which will pick up dynamically created elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
```

Seen here in this working snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {
    alert('Hi');
    $('.box .btn').remove();
    $('.btn').clone().appendTo('.box'); 
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">ShoW</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set event once more again after clone.
then, you can declare your event callback as a function, and set event again after cloning on the cloned element, like this:

```
function appendShowButton() {
    alert('Hi');
    $('.box .btn').remove();
    var newEl = $('.btn').clone().appendTo('.box');
    newEl.on('click', appendShowButton);
    return false;
}

$('.btn').on("click", appendShowButton);
```